# Extract particular column data from one sheet to another sheet using auto filter in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel data in sheet. I named the sheet `OB`. How can I pullout data only `C` and `D` columns from `OB` sheet to another sheet using auto filter. Here is my code:

```
Dim ob As Range
Set ob = Worksheets("ob").Range("a3:e27") 'source sheet
Sheet3.Range("A9:t155").ClearContents     'destination sheet
ob.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
ob.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Sheet3.Range("c2").Value       
ob.copy
With Sheet3.Range("a9")                                              
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .Select
End With
ob.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Above code executing very well. It is extracting all columns in `OB` sheet, but I would like to pull out only `C` and `D` Columns from `OB` sheet.
So I wrote following code for it:

```
Dim ob As Range, Dim fc As Range
Set ob = Worksheets("ob").Range("a3:e27") 'source sheet
Sheet3.Range("A9:t155").ClearContents     'destination sheet
ob.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
ob.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Sheet3.Range("c2").Value       
fc = Intersect(ob.Parent.autfilter.Range, ob.Parent.Range("C:D"))
fc.Copy
With Sheet3.Range("a9")                                              
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .Select
End With
ob.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
```

When I run above code, I am getting error code `438` that is `Object doesn't support this property or method`.
Any help?

Comment: What line returns the error?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld ..   fc = Intersect(ob.Parent.autfilter.Range, ob.Parent.Range("C:D"))

Comment: For one thing, `fc` is a range object, so you'll need to use the `Set` keyword.

Comment: `ob.Parent.autofilter.Range` not `ob.Parent.autfilter.Range`

Comment: @Ron   so i wrote like these...  `set fc = Intersect(ob.Parent.autfilter.Range, ob.Parent.Range("C:D"))`     throwing the same err.

Comment: `autfilter` is missing an `o`

Comment: @Ron and CDP1802 ....  Oh..! now it executing well.  tq u